# How to force an image to refresh

Tags: reactjs, background-image

Here is a small project I'm working through: https://codesandbox.io/embed/rwxookx6po.

I have several divs that have a `backgroundImage` property. The url I am hitting is this one: https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/480x480

Every time you visit that url, you will get a new random image from the collection. I thought that because the props aren't changing, I could force my component to update, but that didn't seem to solve the problem:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.image) {
      this.forceUpdate();
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Given I press a button and pass the same image url prop to my component containing the divs with the background images, how can I get the component to reload, giving my divs a new image background?

Comment: Just a note, if you return true in `shouldComponentUpdate` then it will update, so you dont have to call `forceUpdate` there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a timestamp to your updateImage method, like this:

```
updateImage() {
  const width = 480;
  const height = 480;
  const timestamp = Date.now();
  const imageURL = `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/${width}x${height}?t=${timestamp}`;
  return this.props.updateImage(imageURL, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a complete hack, but I believe the issue is that the browser is caching the result of the request, so isn't going to the url again, by replacing

const imageURL = `https://source.unsplash.com/collection/1163637/${width}x${height}?random=${Math.random()}`;

It now works. (Note it takes like 5 secs or so for the url to change the image it provides)